# Remove newline when copying in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

Whenever I copy a line or a word at the end of a line and then paste, it includes a newline.

Is there anyway to prevent this behavior? I don't want it to copy or paste the newline.

Answer (score 2):

End your selection at the end of the word, not the end of the line.

*The newline character gets selected as any other character would. The trailing space in a selection indicates the selection includes the newline.*

To see the difference, "show paragraph marks and other hidden formatting symbols" by either clicking the <kbd>¶</kbd> toolbar button on the Home ribbon (Paragraph section) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>.

I often find it quicker to make the selection with the mouse. If I see the extra space at the end of the selection, I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to shorten the selection by one character: the newline.

Note: You may have some success modifying the following "Editing options" under File (menu), Options, Advanced (left sidebar section):

- When selecting, automatically select entire word
- Use smart paragraph selection
- Use smart cursoring

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent Word from automatically including the new-line?

Comment: The editing options may help (see edited answer). In summary, just make sure the selection doesn't include the trailing space.

Comment: I've turned those options off. And the goal is to simplify the process of copy and pasting. I want to be able to just double click on a word, even if its at the end, and copy and paste. Having to modify the selection after double clicking is a pain. :/